# Using a while loop to get rows using PhpExcel

Tags: javascript, php, phpexcel

I am looking to create javascript arrays with rows taken from an xlsx spread sheet using PHPExcel.

Here is my code

```
$document.ready({
    var rows = new Array();
    var vals = new Array();

    var i = 0;
while(){
    rows[i] = getRow(i);
    vals[i] = getVal(i);
    i++;
}
});

function getRow(i){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }

    }


    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'data.inc.php?x='+i, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}   

function getVal(i){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }


    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }

    }


    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'include.inc.php?x='+i, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

I am not sure what to check for in the parameter of the while loop (Im assuming we do not know how many rows are in the spreadsheet)

Is that my only issue or this the wrong way to go about it?

Also the function getRow return the entire row and getVal returns one column that will be important elsewhere on the page.

Comment: your functions do not return anything. You will most likely have to check for something the functions return.

Comment: Is there a way to get a variable from the php file back to the 'document.read' section while still return the string from response text?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do that. I was asking about the functions getRow and getVal. There is no return value. How does your javascript realise that there is no more data to get? PHP should probably send something special through `'data.inc.php?x='+i` or just return nothing so javascript knows it is done.

Comment: data.inc.php?x='+i echos back a string which is row i

Comment: What does it return if there is no row any more? that means for all i >= len(rows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches you can use:

1) Synchronise your requests:

```
function getRow(i, rows){
    ...

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            if xmlhttp.responseText != '' {
                rows[i] = xmlhttp.responseText;
                getRow(i+1, rows)
            } else {
                // call function that works with rows.
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This function is only called with `getRows(0, rows)` (no loop!).

This is definitely the slowest approach because every request is started as soon as the previous request has finished.

2) Send number of rows first:

You could send the number of rows with the first or with each request, so javascript knows how many rows there are. Then you can loop over the rows and create asynchronous calls as you do now.

3) Send all rows at once:

I don't know your use case, but it looks like a waste of time to call every row separately. Why not make one call and return all of the data at once with linebreaks as delimiters (or something else suiting your data). If your data is really huge you could still break down the data into large chunks and combine this with option 1 or option 2.

4) Send data at page load:

Not sure if this is an option it looks like it is since you execute your function on `document.ready`. You could consider writing your data into a special hidden div and read the data from there (with javascript) into your variables. That way you avoid all the ajax calls. This is probably the fastest if you want to load all data anyway.

Note: you might consider using jQuery which makes working with ajax a lot easier. Check [jQuery get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for example.

Comment: Thank you! running well now

Comment: just out of curiousity: which approach did you take?

Comment: I used the recursive approach to populate an array on page load and only referenced the array from that point on.